# Distinct Stream in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm writing a flutter app which sends commands via BlueTooth (FlutterBlue) to a device. The device controlls some LEDs.
The communication is working in general quite well but:
On the UI I have a slider controlling the light intensity. When I pull the slider there are more values generated than the bluetooth backend can handle.

In my first implementation I was sending the data directly to the bluetooth characteristic, resulting in exceptions from the bluetooth backend and some values get lost. It's hard to fade light down to zero.

In my second approach I'm using a stream and an `await for` loop to send the data. Now all values are send without any exceptions but it takes several seconds after releasing the slider until all values are send. Since I want direct visual feedback on the LEDs, this is not an option.

Since there are multiple commands of the same type to be send, I can skip all commands of the same type which were added while the bluetooth send routine was processing a write event.

I saw that there is a `Stream.Distinct` method but: It returns a new stream. So I have to exit my `await for` loop and handle the new stream.

Is there a way of removing undesired events from an existing stream without creating a new stream where I have to listen to?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
class MyBlueToothDevice {
  BluetoothDevice _device;
  List<BluetoothCharacteristic> _characteristics =
      List<BluetoothCharacteristic>();

  final _sendStream = StreamController<Tuple2<SendCommands, List<int>>>();

  MyBlueToothDevice(this._device) {
    _writeNext();
  }

  Future<void> write(SendCommands command, List<int> value) async {
    if (isConnected) {
      _sendStream.add(Tuple2<SendCommands, List<int>>(command, value));
      // await _characteristics[command.index].write(value).catchError((value) {
      //   print("Characteristics.write error: $value");
      // });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _writeNext() async {
    await for (var tuple in _sendStream.stream) {
      await _characteristics[tuple.item1.index]
          .write(tuple.item2)
          .catchError((value) {
        print("Characteristics.write error: $value");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use application state management to receive all the events from your slider. The state manager will then rate-limit the messages to the device to something it can handle, and also ensure that the most recent message is not lost.

A very basic solution would receive the slider value and update the value in the state manager. A periodic timer with a suitable rate could then update that value to the device; possibly only if the value actually changed since the last time it was sent.